# LaTeX not rendering in webpage

Tags: latex, render, html

Why is LaTeX not rendering in 
[this](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/neural_networks_supervised.html)
page?

Comment: Hi I'm new here, i want to know why the question has been downvoted. What more could have I done & asked? Thanks.

Comment: Most likely because you didn't show *any* research effort, and you're pointing to an offsite location. A couple years down the line, when that site doesn't exist anymore, this question will be useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page doesn't recognizes LaTeX. To make it recognize, add the following CDN MathJax script:

```
 <script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
    MathJax.Hub.Config({tex2jax: {inlineMath: [['$','$'], ['\\(','\\)']]}});
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" async
    src="https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_CHTML">
  </script>
```

Also, add $ before any LaTeX statement in the page.

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down for migration tips.